# ndb query works locally in test but not in deployment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an ndb query that works properly locally using Google App Engine Launcher, but when I deploy the application to GAE the query can not find any matches in the database (I created entries in the database the same way in both environments).

The Query is:

```
user = users.get_current_user()
_website_sect_name = 'TVplus_Access'
account_chk = Account.chk_account(user.email(), _website_sect_name)
```

The ndb Models and function are:

```
DEFAULT_WEBSITE_NAME = 'TVplus_Access'

def access_lvl_key(website_sect_name=DEFAULT_WEBSITE_NAME):
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a Access_lvl entity with website_sect_name."""
    return ndb.Key('Access_lvl', website_sect_name)

class Account(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual Access_lvl entry."""
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    nickname = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    author = ndb.UserProperty()

    @classmethod
    def chk_account(self, _email, _website_sect_name):
        no_acct = 0
        try: 
            website_key = ndb.Key('Access_lvl', _website_sect_name)
            account_email = Account.query(Account.email == _email, ancestor=website_key).order(-Account.date).get().to_dict()
            return account_email
        except:
            return no_acct
```

The function which adds users is:

```
class Adduser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):

        website_sect_name = self.request.get('website_sect_name',
                                      DEFAULT_WEBSITE_NAME)
        account = Account(parent=access_lvl_key(website_sect_name))

        if users.get_current_user():
            account.author = users.get_current_user()

        account.email = self.request.get('email')
        account.put()

        account.nickname = self.request.get('nickname')
        account.put()

        query_params = {'website_sect_name': website_sect_name}
        self.redirect('/useradmin?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))
```

On my local machine the return response for Account.chk_account() is:

{'date': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 2, 22, 6, 22, 854000), 'nickname': u'Roger', 'email': u'roger@test.com', 'author': users.User(email='admin@test.com',_user_id='123300217217163669814')}

But on the deployment server, the function returns the except code from "no_acct" of 0, which tells me that chk_account() came up empty for some reason (The email account roger@test.com has been added to TVplus_Access in both environments)

Comment: Check your app-engine logs. May be you need to add a new datastore index for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with in chk_account= definition. Removed '.order(-Account.date)' from Account.query(). Corrected section of code:

```
@classmethod
    def chk_account(self, _email, _website_sect_name):
        no_acct = 0
        try: 
            website_key = ndb.Key('Access_lvl', _website_sect_name)
            account_email = Account.query(Account.email == _email, ancestor=website_key).get().to_dict()
            return account_email
        except:
            return no_acct
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember GAE remote control panel has some sort of tool to check database structure and entries. can you access it and see if account you added is truly there?

Comment: That's a good idea. Just checked the Datastore Viewer and I see the entry with the correct id, email, nickname, and author. If I click on the id it brings up: "Decoded entity key: Access_lvl: name=TVplus_Access > Account: id=5707702298738688" along with the properties. That looks correct, but when I click on  "Access_lvl: name=TVplus_Access" it gives me the entity key, but below that it says "This entity doesn't exist" -- which seems like that could be the problem?

Comment: did you create this row manually or from inside your application, there might be a formatting problem if you did it manually. i would recommend that you delete this row entirely and add it from inside the app. if you have already done it from inside the app try to query for all entries. see whether it is included.

Comment: Everything created inside the app. When looking at one of the 'Account' entities, there's no parent listed so there's the problem. I'll edit the question with the code that creates entries.